# Make a class defined in extern "C" block able to reference method outside

Tags: ios, methods, mpmovieplayercontroller, extern

I'm trying to write a simple plugin for Unity3d iOS which you might have heard about that streams video. I actually managed to do that, the streaming video bit works.

Now i'm trying to add functionality that is part of the plugin to detect for a swipe gesture and send a message to Unity. I have no experience with Objective C, and currently not interested in learning the ins and outs as i'm only looking to find a solution for this one specific problem.

So i have managed to Google all the stuff required to stream the actual video, and also some code for registering swipe gestures. The problem is though that, in defining the UISwipeGestureRecognizer you are expected to assign an action method to it. But the function doing the video streaming is being defined in an extern "C" block which is required so that it can be referenced in Unity.

The method assigned to the gesture recognizer though has to be defined (i think) in the regular framework of an iOS app, but my suspicion is that this creates the problem of the gesture recognizer class being unaware of the method defined outside the extern "C" block.

So now when i run it, the video starts streaming but as soon i start swiping the screen it all crashes. Presumably because the method assigned cannot be referenced is my guess.

My question is... How do i make this happen, maybe there's something obvious that i'm unaware of ? The important thing is to make it work in a function that is defined in an extern "C" block, because that after all is required by Unity.

This is the actual code i put together so far:

http://www.hastebin.com/ragocorola.m <-- complete code

To surmise the loadLevel method how should it be declared ?

```
extern "C" {


    void _playVideo(const char *videoFilepath)
    {

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:CreateNSString(videoFilepath)];

        MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]  
        initWithContentURL:url];

        player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
        player.view.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(player.view.transform, 
                                CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2));

        UIWindow *backgroundWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];

        [player.view setFrame:backgroundWindow.frame];
        [backgroundWindow addSubview:player.view];



       UISwipeGestureRecognizer * swipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] 
       initWithTarget:swipe action:@selector(loadLevel:)];

       [swipe setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp | 
        UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft 
       |UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)];


       [player.view addGestureRecognizer:swipe];

       [player play];


    }


}
```

Comment: A comment in your code says an 'extern C' block is only required in a .mm or a .cpp file. You've got a .m file there, so is it strictly necessary?

Comment: the Extern C block is required so that the function be referenced for use in Unity3D. It's not an .m file btw its an .mm file, thats just the link hastebin generated coincidentally. The file name in my Xcode project is called VideoPlugin.mm

Comment: The function is referenced in code for use in Unity3D like this:

[DllImport ("__Internal")]
private static extern void _playVideo (string videoFilepath);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `swipe` is undefined when you are passing it as a target.  Who know's what's on the stack when it's passed?  This results in a method being sent to a bad location in memory when you swipe.

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer * swipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] 
initWithTarget:swipe action:@selector(loadLevel:)];
```

this is equivalent to:

```
id undefinedTarget;
UISwipeGestureRecognizer * swipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] 
    initWithTarget:undefinedTarget action:@selector(loadLevel:)];
```

Your target needs to be an instance of a class that defines the `loadLevel:` method.

---

Edit (after chasing your link): i.e. an instance of `VideoPlugin`.

Though the second problem you will have is that method `loadLevel:` is different from `loadLevel`.  Make sure they are consistent.

Comment: Thank you so much for commenting. I kind of suspected this should be a problem, but all the examples i found declared self as a target which i had no idea of what it is and also was determined to be an undeclared identifier by Xcode if i tried. Could you perhaps provide me with an example that explains how to create a class that defines the LoadLevel: method ( i suspect that is - (void)loadLevel ) and then create an instance of that ? I would be very grateful :)

Comment: Does this make sense in the context of my code ?

VideoPlugin *swipetarget = [[VideoPlugin alloc] init];

Comment: Glad you got it working. Obviously you were on the right track creating an instance as above.  The `self` variable is a hidden parameter to all methods of a class and references the instance you are acting in.  It's only valid within a method; you are in a C function, thus no `self` variable.

Comment: If this answer was what you needed, go ahead and "accept" it. http://stackoverflow.com/about